# Adding methods in type() generated objects in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am generating objects using type for using some of the code that is previously written

```
# Assume that myAppObjDict is already initialized.
myAppObj=type("myAppClass", (object,),myAppObjDict)
```

Now I want to add a method say myValue()in it so that if I should be able to call

```
value=myAppObj.myValue()
```

What should be the approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the methods to `myAppObjDict` before you create the class:

```
def myValue(self, whatever):
    pass
myAppObjDict['myValue'] = myValue

# Assume that myAppObjDict is already initialized.
myAppObj=type("myAppClass", (object,),myAppObjDict)
```

Alternatively define a base class containing the methods and include it in your tuple of base classes.

```
class MyBase(object):
    def myValue(self): return 42

# Assume that myAppObjDict is already initialized.
myAppObj=type("myAppClass", (MyBase,),myAppObjDict)
```

Comment: I am getting the error 
TypeError: unbound method myValue() must be called with myAppClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead).
What may be the cause as when I try myAppObj().myValue() it works.

Comment: Solved it by using myAppObj=type("myAppClass", (object,),myAppObjDict)()

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to assign any function to the class after creation:

```
def method(self):
    print self.__class__.__name__


def my_class (object):
    pass


my_class.method = method

o = my_class()
o.method()
```

You can do this assignment at any time, and all object will have the new method added, event those already created.

After all, Python is a dynamic language :)

Comment: I think I had it could  not be that easy  moment while thinking about it.